# Where should I go for non-Q&A DSP discussions?

Tags: discussion

I've been apart of DSP stack exchange for a handful of years now and have received (and occasionally provided) useful answers to technical/academic type questions.

However, I often cut many of these "discussions" short since stack exchange websites are reserved for Q&A type dialog. I've also wanted to ask more general/open questions regarding projects and hobbies which I know don't follow the format of DSP stack exchange.

So my question here: What good websites/forums would you all suggest to have more open discussions related to DSP? For example, I've wanted to get feedback on good FPGA development platforms for learning FPGA DSP implementation but don't really know where to ask that question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One place to take discussions here on SE.SP is the [post-processing chat room.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1090/post-processing) this does require a certain amount of reputation before you can see it and post it.

Many of the old-timers here started out on the internet discussing signal processing on the [`comp.dsp`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.dsp/BgeLwykHTcs/21x-RQgiNWYJ) usenet newsgroup. The newsgroup isn't quite what it was in its heyday, but it's still reasonably active.

My own first verifiable internet post is there on [July 19, 1991.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.dsp/BgeLwykHTcs/21x-RQgiNWYJ)

Answer (score 0):

There is also the forum at [dsprelated.com](https://www.dsprelated.com/forums).  Many of the regular members here at DSP.SE are also regular there.  Several of us also write blog articles hosted at that site.  The forum is much more slow moving, but discussions are definitely welcome.  Indeed, they are really the focus.