# post-processing chat room is frozen, related items in other sites or info potentially of interest to community or mods unpostable; a good thing?

Tags: discussion, chat

I went to post a DSP related question in Astronomy SE [Why does the background noise in this image of 2020 QG look like corduroy?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/38757/7982) and could not even see the earlier existence of the chat room, no matter which sorting category I clicked

[image: this site's chat room is somewhat invisible]

I then found that [this answer](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1656) names the room I'm looking for, but it's been locked for 121 days due to inactivity.

@NikeDattani moderator at Matter Modeling SE [posted a site-related comment](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55385361#55385361) in an unrelated chat room, presumably out of desperation.

Is leaving this room locked and somewhat invisible a good thing? Or should it be unfrozen and occasionally pinged to keep it available?

Comment: I unfroze the room (in case this helps you).

Comment: @jojek thanks!!

Comment: @jojek, We need to unfreeze it again. Thank You.

Comment: It's unfrozen now, @Royi

Comment: @jojek now I forgot what I wanted to say :-) But thanks!